# Dynamically change span text when using jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to dynamically change the text of a span when a dialog is loaded using jQuery mobile. Following is the code present in my first page.

```
<a data-transition="turn" id="profile-btn" data-rel="dialog" href="profile.html">Some Text</a>
```

In the profile.html I have

```
<div data-role="page" id="profile-page" data-role="dialog">
    <span id="username">username</span>
</div>
```

Following is the js code

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#profile-page', function () { 
        jQuery("#username").text(localStorage.user);
    });     
});
```

My above setup is not working. Do you guys know what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: There is no error, I am sure that the pageinit event is captured as I debugged it by putting a console.log in it.

Comment: Do you have any duplicate `id` here?

Comment: You cant use `data-role` twice, if you're using JQM 1.4, use `data-dialog="true"` with `data-role="page"`. Remove `.load()` function and replace `pageinit` with `pagecreate` if using JQM 1.4. For JQM 1.3 leave `pageinit` and remove `load()`.

Comment: Thank you Omar, all the changes you suggested got it to work :)